# SharePoint 2013 server API - no LimitedWebPartManager?

Tags: web-part, 2013, splimitedwebpartmanager

I have a SharePoint 2013 development environment.  The Microsoft.SharePoint.dll assembly does not contain LimitedWebPartManager.  I want to use a sandbox solution to provision a page and the web parts on it.

I'm not going insane: the LimitedWebPartManager class does not exist, and SPPage and the other classes don't have GetLimitedWebPartManager methods.  I've checked with ILSpy/Reflector, the methods and classes are simply not there.

What gives, and what can I do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Server Side `LimitedWebPartManager` class is not available in Sandbox Solutions (both 2010 and 2013). However there is a [SP.WebParts.LimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408753%28v=office.14%29.aspx) class in the JavaScript Client Object Model which you can use in your Sandbox Solution.

See this link for examples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185010(v=office.14).aspx

Hope this helps.